# Regex to remove a tail after a date

Tags: r, regex, date, substitution

I've looked around but I'm having trouble utilizing regex to remove the "*/tues" from a date variable using the sub() function.

all variables in a$date look like this:

```
01/01/2017/Sun
01/03/2017/Tues
```

etc..

And i'm trying to do this:

```
sub(a$date,"*7/\\*","")
```

I'm sure I've just messed up the regex.

How do I escape the first two `/` and tell it only to delete the third one and everything after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
sub("\\/[^0-9]+$","", a$date)
#[1] "01/01/2017" "01/03/2017"
```

---

Or with `substr`

```
substr(a$date, 1, 10)
#[1] "01/01/2017" "01/03/2017"
```

#### data

```
a <- data.frame(date = c("01/01/2017/Sun", "01/03/2017/Tues"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is simply to truncate your string:

```
library("stringr")

# truncate date after 10 characters
a$date <- str_trunc(a$date,10)
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is awesome.  Also a valid answer.